# How to programmatically update specific row in GWT CellTable

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

I have 5 rows in GWT CellTable. The table has 2 columns id, value. I have gwt timer which must periodically update value for specific id. So in timer implementation i call something like that:

```
....
double value = calcValueForId(id);
update(id, value);
.....
private void update(int id, double value) {
// here i have access to cell table instance and data provider (AsyncDataProvider)
// how to access row with given id and update its value column
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to retrieve the item (of the type you used to parameterize your `CellTable`) and then you can call `updateRowData` of your `AsyncDataProvider` (or `setRowData` on the `CellTable`) with the item's index. This will tell that the items (actually only one in your case) starting at the given index have changed, so the table must be redrawn (for now, the whole table will be refreshed, but a later version of GWT might add "per row" refresh).

In your particular case though (only 5 rows and 2 columns), maybe `CellTable` isn't the best fit…

Comment: Yes it isn't, but it has build in pagination, and i need client side pagination. No other table can provide that fast (excluding paging scrolling table which is a nightmare for me).